# Button targeting 2 'li's in 2 different 'ul's in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get a close button to close 2 LIs but they're in 2 different ULs - LIs generated by jQuery dynamically.
When someone enters an item / qty and clicks add they are rendered into a new LI but when they include the pricing, it renders in a different LI
So pressing the "X" in the Item/Qty to close the specific LI wont affect the price corresponding to that item.

Also the "Clear" button works fine just the individual LIs

Any suggestions on fixing this issue without having to add the "X" on the price LI as well?

[I hope my explanation makes sense, you can see the code here](http://codepen.io/Simetria/pen/YPGqMa)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Adds typed items and qty to the list 
    $('#add').on('click', function () {
        var item = $('#list').val();
        var qty = $('#qty').val();
        $('#list-a').append('<li>' + '<div class="delete"></div>' + qty + ' ' + item + '</li>');

        var price = $('#price').val();
        $('#list-b').append('<li>' + '$' + price + '</li>');

        // Resets input field to empty and focus
        $('#list').val('').focus();
        $('#qty, #price').val('');
    });

    // Fires Add to List button when enter is clicked
    $('#list, #qty, #price').keyup(function (event) {
        if (event.keyCode === 13) {
            $('#add').click();
        }
    });

    // Deletes/fades out 'li' when X is clicked
    $('#list-a').on('click', '.delete', function () {
        var listItem = $(this).closest('li');
        listItem.fadeOut(500, function () {
            listItem.remove();
        });
    });

    // Clear all items on the list and focus back on new shopping item
    $('#clear').on('click', function () {
        var li = $('li');
        li.fadeOut(500, function () {
            $(li).remove('li');
        });
        $('#list').val('').focus();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to remove the `li` with the same sibling index from the next `ul`:

```
$('#list-a').on('click', '.delete', function () {

    var listItem = $(this).closest('li'),
        index = listItem.index();

    listItem.parent().next('ul').find('li:eq(' + index + ')').add(listItem)
    .fadeOut(500, function () {
        $(this).remove();
    });

});
```

#### Demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/emdyqX

Comment: One more quick question if I may... If I now want to take the prices added to the right ul and add them up in a input field showing how much the total is, how would I approach it. This is just a fun project for me to learn jquery but these more complex functions still go over my head.

Comment: Here is a quick code to calculate total amount. You will need to put this sum into necessary place. http://jsfiddle.net/4rc4wav0/

Comment: Thank you once again. If my input field to display the total price has an id of #total-items, would this be enough to get the total to display in it? $('#total-items').val(total);

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#list-a').on('click', '.delete', function() {
    var listItem = $(this).closest('li');
 var ind = listItem.index();

    listItem.fadeOut(500, function() {
        listItem.remove();
    });

$('#list-b').find('li').eq(ind).fadeOut(500, function() {
        $(this).remove();
    });


});
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OPRzKx